# How to remove the instance of ManyToMany field?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='organisation_user',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    location    = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    qualification_status = (
        ('Pending for verification','Pending for verification'),
        ('Verified','Verified'),
        )
    qualification   = models.CharField(max_length=100,choices=qualification_status,default='Pending for verification',blank=True)
    members         = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='organisation_members',blank=True)

class Organisation_member(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    organisation    = models.ForeignKey(Organisation,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='organisation_staff')
    member_name     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='organisation_staff_member',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    is_admin        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have this signal for creation of `Organisation_member` model:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Organisation)
def organisation_admin(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    for member in instance.members.all():
        if Organisation_member.objects.filter(user=instance.user,organisation=Organisation.objects.filter(user=instance.user,name=instance.name).first(),member_name=member).exists():
            pass
        else:
            Organisation_member.objects.update_or_create(User=instance.User,organisation=Organisation.objects.filter(user=instance.user,name=instance.name).first(),member_name=member,is_admin=False)
```

The signal indicates that when I add a member in my manytomany field it will automatically create a `Organisation_member` object of the selected member.

The signal works perfectly fine.

My problem is the reverse i.e. when I try to delete an object of `Organisation_member` it should also remove the member from the manytomany relationship of the parent model.

I have tried this:

```
@login_required()
def delete_members(request, pk):
    user_organisation = get_object_or_404(Organisation, user=request.user)
    member_to_delete = Organisation_member.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    if member_to_delete.exists():
        member_to_delete[0].delete()
        for member in user_organisation.members.all():
            user_organisation.members.remove(member=member_to_delete[0])
    return redirect(reverse('userprofile:organisation_member_list'))
```

But it does not removes the member from the parent model..

Anyone who knows the solution please help.

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't the script `member_to_delete[0].delete()` deleted the contents in the object? So when you are using `user_organisation.members.remove(member=member_to_delete[0])`, you are deleting nothing.

Comment: It deletes the object for sure but it is not removing the object from manytomany relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@login_required()
def delete_members(request, pk):
    user_organisation = get_object_or_404(Organisation, user=request.user)
    member_to_delete = get_object_or_404(Organisation_member, pk=pk)
    user_organisation.members.remove(member_to_delete.member_name)
    member_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect(reverse('userprofile:organisation_member_list'))
```

[Refer Django offical doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of using this kind of relationship would be to specify `Organisation_member` as the `through` model for `members` in `Organisation`. Then the database takes care of it for you without any signals.

```
class Organisation(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='Organisation_member')
```

The only problem is that you currently have two references to `User` in `Organisation_member`: `member_name` and `user`. Why? You probably only need one and should delete the other. If there is a reason for having two different users in `Organisation_member`, you need to specify the fields to use for the relationship:

```
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        through='Organisation_member',
        through_fields=('organisation', 'member_name'))
```

That's it, `Organisation_member`s are automatically added and removed whenever you add or remove a user to or from `members`.